# Before getting the records csv gets downloaded

Tags: php, excel

I'm working on the php excel export. Here i'm facing some problems like there is huge number of data almost 8000 records. The data are placed in the cell perfectly. What was my issue is

On 3000 records itself csv gets downloaded. How can i fix this ?

There are no more 3000 to 8000 how can i do this ?

**Example Code**

```
    <?php
    // Connection 

                $tamdsreport_billing_qry = db_query($_SESSION['tamdsreport_billing_qry']);
                                while($result_tamdsreport_billing_qry = db_fetch_array($tamdsreport_billing_qry)){

                                  $datacenter_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['datacenter'];
                                  $cid_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['cid'];
                                  $rid_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['rid'];
                                  $datastore_name_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['datastore_name'];
                                  $cloud_type_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['cloud_type'];
                                  $storage_type_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['storage_type'];
                                  $avg_capacity_gb_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['avg_capacity_gb'];
                                  $avg_free_space_gb_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['avg_free_space_gb'];
                                  $avg_space_consumed_gb_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['avg_space_consumed_gb'];
                                  $gb_used_param = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['gb_used'];
                                  $start_date = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['start_date'];
                                  $end_date = $result_tamdsreport_billing_qry['end_date'];


                                 $html3[] = "<tr><td>$datacenter_param</td><td>$start_date</td><td>$end_date</td><td>$cid_param</td><td>$rid_param</td><td>$datastore_name_param</td><td>$cloud_type_param</td><td>$storage_type_param</td><td>$avg_capacity_gb_param</td><td>$avg_free_space_gb_param</td><td>$avg_space_consumed_gb_param</td><td>$gb_used_param</td></tr>";

                        }



        $html = "<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><tr><td><h3>Storage Usage for A0CA </h3> </td></tr><tr bgcolor='#445fea'><td>Data Center</td><td>Report Start Date</td><td>Report End Date</td><td>CID</td><td>RID</td><td>Data Store Name</td><td>Cloud Type</td><td>Storage Type</td><td>Avg capacity GB</td><td>Avg free space GB</td><td>Avg space consume GB</td><td>GB Used</td></tr>".implode("\r\n", $html3). "</table>";


        $fileName = 'tamdrp_billing_export_US.xls';

}
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
echo $html;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Are you certain that 8000 records are generated? I'd rather save these records to a temp file and header this with `readfile($tempfile)`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to try with PHPExcel.
I wish it will worked for you.

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPEx     = new PHPExcel();
$filename     = 'output.xlsx';
$objWorksheet = $objPHPEx->getActiveSheet(0); 
$objPHPEx->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(14); 
$objPHPEx->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S1',123);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPEx, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('products_inventory_files/' . $filename);
```